# Self-referencing AWS API Gateway (REST) in resource policy

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I have a private REST-style API Gateway and would like to tighten it down with a resource policy specific to itself. In CDK (LambdaRestApi), I can get the region and account from the Stack but there is of course the problem that the arn:aws:execute-api needs the API ID which isn't available until creation.

So I create the resource in the stack and then try to create the PolicyDocument and cast the LambdaRestApi down to L1 and use setPolicy but apparently the API ID isn't placeholder enough and I end with a cyclic dependency kaboom when the stack is actually created

Pointers?

Comment: What is the cloudformation template code with those resources?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you add a dependsOn and create the policy only after the API is available?